# dragging dropping in iframe stopped working second time

Tags: jquery, iframe, draggable, droppable

Problem: I am working on single page web-portal.
Main Page has iframe.
Now every document will be loaded inside the iframe.

Page1.aspx is master which has iframe:

[1] When Page2.aspx is loaded in iframe
first time i am binding droppable and draggable events it works properly.

[2] Now I am reloading Page2.aspx calling function to bind both the event. 
This time draggable droppable stopped working.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: calling two function  menuEvents() to bind menu events in parent. Calling bindDrop() from Page2.aspx after load to bind droppable event.

Comment: Please refer this for code : jsfiddle.net/teligaurav/rz1qoj76/3 my problem is after loading document by click on button. the drad drop stops working in IE on second time when I re-load child document. I am using IE10

Comment: Try this Fiddle [1]
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jzo5et11/9/

Answer (score 0):

After the iframe is reloaded, the container the droppable was bound to does not exist anymore. This seems to cause the error in IE. To fix this, you need to tell the droppable plugin that the container is no drop target anymore.

```
$( "iframe" ).contents().find( "#iframe_container" ).droppable('destroy');
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzo5et11/12/